# Error Service Broker Service

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

When I run the below command, I the below error. I wasn't able to find any solutions to the error.

```
USE [my_db]
GO

CREATE SERVICE [//Db/DbInitatorService]  ON QUEUE [dbo].[InitiatorDbQueue] ([//Db/DbContract])
GO
```

> An entity of type service cannot be owned by a role, a group, or by
>   principals mapped to certificates or asymmetric keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of the error is that you log in into SQL Server database either via a Windows group membership, or application role, or key / certificate-mapped user. For your statement to succeed, you should be authenticated as a straight SQL or Windows user.

You can start investigating your situation with a query like this:

```
select dp.name, dp.type, dp.type_desc
from sys.database_principals dp
where dp.principal_id = database_principal_id();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can grant ownership of the service when you create it to any single user in the database. Like so:

```
USE [my_db]
GO

CREATE SERVICE [//Db/DbInitatorService]
AUTHORIZATION [someUser]
ON QUEUE [dbo].[InitiatorDbQueue] ([//Db/DbContract])
GO
```